# MBR bootsector that boots the active partition

Tags: boot, grub, bootloader, mbr

I have the burg bootloader currently installed on my mbr (+ the following sectors), and I would like to install it on the boot partition, and replace the mbr with a simple one that will boot the partition marked as active ("boot" flag in some partitioning tools).

Although I know enough programming to write in assembly a bootsector that will find the first active partition and load it, I'd rather use an existing one.

Where could I find such a bootsector? Maybe the default windows bootsector does that?

### Why I want to do that

I have a tool on windows (3DS Max) that consistently breaks the burg bootloader each time it is run. Apparently, it includes an "anti-piracy" software called [FlexNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexNet_Publisher) that tags your copmputer to say "hey, 3DS Max was installed here, unfortunately it writes that information in one of the 63 sectors following the bootsector, and burg is installed there (I would call such behavior either "malware" or a "critical bug").

Recent versions of grub now detect when the application has broken your boot, and use different sectors, but burg (a graphical variant of grub) [lacks that patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/burg/+bug/867495).

I have therefore decided to install burg on the boot partition, mark that partition as active, and just ave a single-sector bootloader, that will find the active partition and boot it (PC bootsectors used to do just that in the good ol' times).

Comment: Why not request the patch be included in burg at their [Launchpad bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/burg)

Comment: @ECarterYoung Yeah, I'll do that anyway, but even if they include the patch right now, I'll either have to recompile burg by hand, or wait for the ubuntu developers to package the newer version, so I'm still interested in the "quick fix" :) .

Comment: @ECarterYoung actually the bug has already been reported in 2011 https://bugs.launchpad.net/burg/+bug/867495 but it's still consisdered as "status=new, importance=undecided" so although I'd be delighted to voluteer on the project, I currently lack the time.

Comment: I think you may have run into something that is [by design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexNet_Publisher#Issues_with_Bootloaders)

Comment: @ECarterYoung Oh yes, it totally seems to be by design, and in my opinion, a software that breaks your boot by design is, well, malware, basically :) . But still, I think I found a way to circumvent the problem (installing burg on the boot partition, rather than at the begining of the disk), and I'm just missing the bootsector that will chain-load the bootloader installed on the active partition.

Answer (score 1):

> I have therefore decided to install burg on the boot partition, mark that partition as active, and just have a single-sector bootloader, that will find the active partition and boot it

Good, because it's as bad for boot manager/boot loader programs to assume that that space is free for the taking as it is for FlexNet Publisher to do so.  Aside from the fact that on EFI partitioned discs it isn't free *at all*, it's only accident and habit that make it the case on *some* MBR partitioned discs.  After all, it has now been quite a few years since the world started *not* to begin the first partition at the start of "track" 1, and to instead align partitions at anything from 4KiB to multiple-GiB boundaries.

> (PC bootsectors used to do just that in the good ol' times).

And there are many ways of writing bootstrap code that does that into the Master Boot Record, from the Microsoft utility

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr
```

through a FreeBSD utility

```
fdisk -B ada0
```

to a Linux utility

```
ms-sys --mbrsyslinux /dev/sda
```

I've written two `newmbr` programs myself.

There are scads of utilities to do this, on "rescue" discs and in partitioning tools.  I hear that some people even have code to do this on EFI partitioned hard discs.  ☺

### Further reading

- Jan van Wijk (2012-09-11).  [*MBR or EBR area operations*](http://www.dfsee.com/dfsee/dfsmenu-fdisk.php#id03837).  DFSEE Manual.
- [`bootsect`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd744577(v=ws.10).aspx).  TechNet.  2009-10-22.  Microsoft corporation.
- [`fdisk`(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdisk&sektion=8).  2013-10-01.  FreeBSD manual pages.
- [`ms-sys`](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) SourceForge.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011) [*A PC/AT-style MBR bootstrap program for EFI partitioned discs*](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/mbrcode-efi.html).  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011) [The "active" partition attribute](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/pcat-boot-process.html#Active).  *The PC/AT boot process*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that once you have installed your boot loader your [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record) is already setup correctly with BootStrap code. That is all you need. If you have transferred your boot loader to another partition then all you need to do is to change the active partition flag in MBR. Also make sure that partition type is correct.

You can change that flag by manually editing your MBR ([dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) command + a decent hex editor will do, partition entries start at offset 1BEh) or alternatively use some utility like [fdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk) or [gparted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted).

***EDIT:**

Instead of transferring you can also try to instal BURG directly on a separate partition same way as if you would do with GRUB:

```
sudo burg-install –force –root-directory=/media/BootPartitionMountPoint  /dev/sda
```

This would configure a correct MBR with the BootStrap code containing instruction to jump to your **BootPartitionMountPoint** and load BURG.

Comment: Oh. I thought that when installing grub or burg to a partition, they wouldn't change the MBR, but now I think about it I'm probably wrong. I'll try that then, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the command I have posted in the answer. `–root-directory=/media/BootPartitionMountPoint` specifies where to install actual BURG. The last argument (in this case `/dev/sda`, just an example) actually points to the disk where MBR will be written. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ah, I misread the command indeed. That's not going to work as far as I can tell: it will install grub in the mbr + **the following sectors** (and that's the problem), and tell it to find the extra files in the partition mounted in `/media/BootPartitionMountPoint`, but it still needs more than just the mbr at the beginning of the disk. I'll try installing to /dev/sda1 and see if that changes the mbr to a simple one when I get home, though.